# Clean/Rebuild Run

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

As I'm making my application, I've been able to just run my project and it runs with the changes all made. As my project is getting larger, I have to go Clean Solution, Rebuild Solution and Run...Recently I also upgraded "Team System" edition my dad has, because of its testing tools

Why is this happening? is it because of something I've done in my project or is it because of the different version of Visual Studio

Comment: Exactly why do you have to rebuild the solution, what error are you getting?

Comment: why do you want to clean and rebuild every time? just compiling the delta changes should be just fine.

Comment: well... I'm not getting any errors, it just doesn't recognize my changes when I run click run(as I was before), Only a few warnings..which are ok, they were there before. It's pretty strange I can't figure out what it is.

I'd like to not have to do it, the only thing I can think of is the difference in versions of Visual Studio. Well that's the only thing I have changed

Comment: for the past few days I've just been cleaning, rebuilding. That's getting very annoying

Comment: I am not sure this is what you are asking for..so just check one. Goto Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run. There is a combo box shich says "On run, when projects are out of date" Select the option you want.

Comment: yeah, I've already tried that, thanks though :)